# ¿Problema al llenar JTable con Query?

Tags: java, mvc, poo, java-8, arraylist

Hola Colegas estoy programando en java en patrón MVC y me tope con este bucle dentro de mi código. estoy utilizando arraylist

```
//Arraylist para llenar una jtable con arreglos

 public ArrayList<String[]> Select(){

            try{
                 Statement s = getConexion().createStatement();
                 rs = s.executeQuery("Select idclie,status from cliente");
                 //System.out.println("El select si se hace");

                matResultado=new ArrayList<String[]>();
                String Fila[] = new String[2];



                //System.out.println("Array List se llena");

                while (rs.next()){
                    System.out.println("Entro al while");
                    Fila=new String[2];
                    for (int x=0;x<2;x++){       

                        //System.out.println("Entro al for del while");
                    //System.out.print(rs.getObject(x+1).toString());
                        Fila[x]=rs.getObject(x+1).toString();

                        //System.out.println("A una llave del final");                          
                    }
                  //  System.out.println("");
                    matResultado.add(Fila);
                }


                System.out.println("Salgo chido frel while");
                if (matResultado.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("mat resutado es nulo");
                    return null;
                }
                System.out.println("math resultado vale"+matResultado.size());
                return matResultado;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

        return null;
    }
```

Funciona pero cuando son mas de 10 registros, el programa muere con e "Too many connections" y me he dado cuenta que hace un bucle al hacer la consulta, pues dependiendo del numero de registros hace 1 while ej: tengo 40 registros, hace 40  'System.out.println("math resultado vale"+matResultado.size());' eso quiere decir que llena mi arreglo 40 veces

Asi es cómo lo mando llamar para llenar la tabla

```
if(pressed.getSource()==V1.btnBuscar){
    if(V1.cbxTipo.getSelectedIndex()==0){

        V1.modelo.setRowCount(0);


        try{
        for (int i=0;i<M1.Select().size() ; i++) {
            V1.modelo.addRow(M1.Select().get(i));
        }

        }

        catch (Exception excp){
            System.out.println(excp.getMessage());
            excp.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que estas llamando al metodo n veces y al no cerrar la conexion al final de cada llamada acaba dando error.

Comment: @Lithorell No de hecho solo lo llamo una vez con un for para llenar la tabla por cada ROW

Comment: Si lo estas llamando varias veces. Y ademas veo que el codigo no tiene ninguna logica. Cuando haces "for (int i=0;i<M1.Select().size() ; i++) {" lo llamas una vez, luego en cada iteracion lo vuelves a llamar con V1.modelo.addRow(M1.Select().get(i));

Comment: Cada vez que haces M1.Select() es una llamada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te he dicho en comentario, tu problema esta en las multiples llamadas que haces.

Cambiando esto lo llamarias solo una vez.

```
if(pressed.getSource()==V1.btnBuscar){
    if(V1.cbxTipo.getSelectedIndex()==0){

       V1.modelo.setRowCount(0);


        try{
            ArrayList<String[] valoresBBDD = M1.Select();
            for (int i=0;i<valoresBBDD .size() ; i++) {
                V1.modelo.addRow(valoresBBDD.get(i));
            }

        }catch (Exception excp){
            System.out.println(excp.getMessage());
            excp.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, funciono perfectamente.